# How can you do AI research by your own?

Tags: research

Let's say you want to do AI research and publish some papers just by your own. Would you send them to an AI journal using just your name? Which AI journals are recommended?

Comment: research and publish are not the same. In the best case, publish follows decades of research. Any particular can offer a paper to near than all science magazine. Recall publish is not mandatory, and nowadays it would be better if 99% of the current papers had not been published, these papers are more related to how universities promote their staff than to its science value. About recommended journals, google for "AI journals ranking" or "AI journals impact factor".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me preface this by acknowledging that this question is prone to opinion. This answer is, in so far as it is possible, primarily *observation* based.

---

My understanding is that, when it comes to publishing in a journal, doing so as an individual (without backing from an institution) is, in general, going to be frowned upon.

As you may know: scientific research, including AI research, is generally subject to [peer review](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scholarly_peer_review). When it comes to journals, this is mandatory. The review process attempts to enhance and preserve the integrety of the information published. As an additional safeguard, submissions will often expected to be backed by endorsement from someone within the academic community (typically an institution).

**However**, and as Pasaba correctly points out (in his comment on the OP), research and publishing are not neccessarily the same thing. Furthermore, not having an endorsement does not not stop you from making a contribution to the field.

For example, you can publish code and/or articles on websites such as Github, and engage with communities of professional and hobbiest researchers around the web, (e.g. this Stack Exchange).

Note that there is also some scope for endorsement without being a direct member of a research institution. For example: arXiv, whilst not strictly a journal, is an open archive that supports endorsement by [request](https://arxiv.org/help/endorsement).

Without knowing your circumstances, it's hard to know exactly what to do. However, my general advice is to find and engage with communities, and build a network of collaborative peers, rather than trying to succeed in an isolated fashion.

Answer (score 2):

To complement Cosmo's response and maybe address the "*using just your name*" part of your question, I would like to acknowledge that biased towards submissions do exist. Reviewers may be biased due to several reasons, such us authors' age, publications record, gender, nationality [(Lotfi and Mahian, 2014)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4214948/).

If you are concerned about these aspects, rest assured that there are mechanisms to ensure that the authors' reputation does not influence reviewers' judgments. A good example is the "[Double-Blind Review](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/social-science-and-medicine/policies/double-blind-peer-review-guidelines)" process, which means that identities from the author(s) and reviewer(s) are concealed throughout the review process.